# php localhost mail not getting sent using xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I have configured my php.ini and sendmail setting as instructed by other people, however i am still not able to send any mails from local host by using the mail() function in PHP.

These are my php.ini [mail function] setting

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25



sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"


;sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"


and this is my sendmail.ini settings

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com


; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587



smtp_ssl=tls


error_logfile=error.log

auth_username= joel.paul69@gmail.com
auth_password= examplepassword
```

My operating system is windows 8. And I am new to PHP or any server side programming.

It would be really helpful if you all could help me out, perhaps send the the correct setting etc. Thanks Guys :D :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `phpMailer`, much easier and works perfect.

you'll need to download these two files and put them in the same directory :

http://goo.gl/TyYgty

then you need to require/include the `class.phpmailer.php`

```
// change the path of the file
require_once("_path_to/class.phpmailer.php");
```

once that done you'll need to configure the `phpMailer()` function settings :

**Note :** you'll need to provide a valid email by going to your domain c-panel and creating an email with password then add them to the configuration below, or you can use `Gmail` as a `host`,`email`,`password` instead of the email if you don't have a host or domain, but in this case the `$mail->Port` will be the `Gmail` port maybe it's `465` and the `$mail->SMTPSecure` will be `ssl`.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "http";
        $mail->Host = "your webmail host domain"; // ex. webmail@domain.com
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->Username = "sender email goes here"; // ex. info@domain.com
        $mail->Password = "sender email password goes here";
        $webmaster_email = "sender email goes here"; // ex. info@domain.com
        $mail->From = $webmaster_email;  
        $mail->FromName = "sender name goes here"; // ex. John Doe
        $mail->AddAddress($email);  
        $mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email); 
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "your message subject goes here";
        $mail->Body = 'your message body goes here'; // take a look on google, how to send html email body

        if(!$mail->Send())  
        {  
            echo 'An error occurred, Please try again later';
        }else {
            echo 'Email Sent!';
        }
```

Then you can use it anywhere, anytime, `localhost`/`webserver`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Gmail security authentication, as Gmail is not allowing login access from low secured apps, one should enable those settings in gmail as follows.

1. Go to the **"Less secure apps"** section in **My Account**.
2. Next to **"Access for less secure apps"**, select **Turn on**.